# Why is extra margin added to the 'body' of my WordPress website in FireFox 32.0.3?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having an issue with my WordPress site in firefox where the body seems to have "margin-top" or padding-top applied. When checking the code with firebug, no such style is shown. This issue is only in Firefox, Please help! Link: http://codecreatif.com/c6/

Comment: remove from #main-header  margin-bottom: 60px

Comment: Wow @LuisP.A. That's weird, why did that cause a gap between the browser window and the body?

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: When you make hover the menu the div goes up and down. I make you a fix above. That means never stay out of the main-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add overflow: hidden at #main-header.
This happens because your menu gets out of the box to make the effect. When you make hover he make a vertical movement (down up), and that space is reserved for that animation.

```
#main-header {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```